# Vuex action not throwing on axios try/catch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vue and Vuex and would like to be able to show API errors inside my component, when these occur in my action. I'm using axios for this example.

This is the action which should just perform a get request, and throw an error when that fails

```
export default {
  async search({ commit }, params) {
    const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/search`, params)
    commit('SET_RESULTS', result.data)
  }
}
```

This is my Search.vue component, which I want to be able to log 'Caught Error', when an api error occurs inside my action

```
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      try {
        this.$store.dispatch('search', this.value)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Caught Error')
      }
    }
  }
```

I do get red console errors, but not the one I'm defining in my Search.vue. So for some reason my action isn't throwing or my Search.vue isn't catching.

Comment: `dispatch` returns a promise, it won't throw an error. So you'd use `this.$store.dispatch(...).catch(err => { ... })`. If you want to use a `try`/`catch` then you'd need to use `async`/`await` on that promise: `await this.$store.dispatch(...)`.

Comment: @skirtle Could you create an answer from that? So I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dispatch` returns a promise, it won't throw an error.

So you'd use a `catch` callback:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('search', this.value).catch(err => {
  console.log('Caught Error')
}).
```

If you want a `try`/`catch` instead then you'd need to use `async`/`await` on that promise:

```js
async onSubmit() {
  try {
    await this.$store.dispatch('search', this.value)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught Error')
  }
}
```